# Adding a function to a URL

Tags: c#, function, redirect

I have got a bit of a problem.

I have two pages (Thumbnail.aspx & FormFilling.aspx); in FormFilling.aspx I have the following code:

```
Response.Redirect("Thumbnail.aspx?productID=" + Request.QueryString["pid"].ToString() + "&")
```

In Thumbnail.aspx I have the following function:

```
private void Preview(){
     //something happens
}
```

What I am trying to do is call that function in `Response.Redirect` Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just call that method in the Page_Load method of Thumbnail.aspx page?

Comment: What do you mean by "Call this function *in* the Response.Redirect? Response.Redirect will send a HTTP 302 code to the web-browser causing it to request the "Thumbnail.aspx" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Preview() function is part of Thumbnail.aspx and you want to call it from FormFilling.aspx, you'll need to either mark the function as static or put it in a central class that both ASPX pages have access to.  A lot of developers will make a PageBase class that ASPX pages derive from, and this would be a great place for logic commonly used by multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's a private method, so even if calling methods like this on an `.aspx` page was possible, this would fail.

You *could* do this with web services - see the [`WebMethodAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.aspx) and [[How Do I:] Create and Call a Simple Web Service in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet) (Video).